# Start new activity using onShake method

Tags: android, android-activity, shake

I'd like to start new activity by using onShake method. Everything is ok but when new activity starts, onShake command is still possible (when i shake my phone 5 times, new activity starts 5 times). What should I do to shake phone and start new activity only once?
Here is my code.

```
public class ACTIVITY extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    ShakeEvent mSensorListener;

    mSensorListener = new ShakeEvent();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


    mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEvent.OnShakeListener() {

      public void onShake() {
          Intent i = new Intent(Shake.this, NEWACTIVITY.class);
          startActivity(i);
      }
    });
}}
```

Excuse me for my bad English. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [unregisterListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#unregisterListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor%29) in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance variable(a boolean) and keep it set to false initially. When `onShake()` is called the first time, check if it is false before starting the new activity. Then change it to true and start the activity. The next time the `onShake()` method gets called, your activity will not start since your instance variable is now set to true.