# Onshake method : activity should start only once

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-sensors

i am starting a activity with onShake method..each time i shake, the activity is getting started but i want the activity to start only the first time i shake...i have seen the similar question here: [Start new activity using onShake method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067633/start-new-activity-using-onshake-method) ..but could not get much from it..below is my code

```
public class ShakeListenerTestActivity extends Activity
{
  private ShakeListener mShaker;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);              

    final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    mShaker = new ShakeListener(this);
    mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
      public void onShake()
      {
   vibe.vibrate(100);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(ShakeListenerTestActivity.this)
          .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
          .setMessage("Do stuff here!!")
          .show();
 }
    });

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
    mShaker.resume();
    super.onResume();
  }
  @Override
  public void onPause()
  {
    mShaker.pause();
    super.onPause();

  }  
}
```

in my shakelistener class i am using unregisterListener in pause() method.

```
 public void pause() {
        if (mSensorMgr != null) {

          mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
          mSensorMgr = null;
        }
      }
```

what am i missing here any suggestion is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you you just get rid of the `mShaker` when it does what it is supposed to do ? After you build `AlertDialog`, just call `mShaker...whatever destroys it` or at least `mShaker.pause`. If this is not the answer, I misunderstood your problem sorry.

Comment: just try puting mShaker.pause into onShake()

Comment: any suggestions on how to start two activities using onshake..here is the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227467/android-activity-setting-number-of-shakes-or-timeframe-for-onshake-method